# Create a ScrollView in Android with bounce effect but without EdgeEffect

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, overscroll

I am working on an Android application and I need to create a custom ScrollView that exhibits a bouncing effect when the user overscrolls, similar to the iOS behavior, but without displaying any EdgeEffect (the glow or fade effect at the edges).

Does anyone know how to create a ScrollView that both bounces back on overscroll and does not show any EdgeEffect? I would prefer a solution that does not involve third-party libraries.